# How to map Nested JSON to an HTML table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapping

I have JSON Data from an API which contains users at different locations. I want to map it to an HTML table that looks like the one shared below.

HTML TABLE: 
[image: HTML TABLE]

JSON DATA:

```
   {
    "data": [{

        "location": "Location 1",
        "Address": "location 1, Address",
        "users": [{
            "name": "Location 1 User",
            "state": "Active"
        }]

    }, {
        "location": "Location 2",
        "Address": "Location 2, Address",


        "users": [{
                "name": "Location 2 User",
                "state": "Active"
            },
            {
                "name": "Location 2 User",
                "state": "Inactive"
            }
        ]

    }]
}
```

If you notice in the third column, both users of the second location are added inside one td element and are listed in one cell. I want to transform my JSON to this sort of table with RAW Javascript.

I have tried different ways but no luck so any help on this would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Definitely get a lot more help showing what you tried that can be tweaked rather than expecting others to do all the code writing for you...which won't happen since this isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: please show your best existing attempt, we can't fix code we can't see.

Comment: Guys! I'm not looking for code fixes /  examples to steal away. I wanted a generic / simple answer to know how it is regularly done since the API / JSON I shared is not antique. 

The original API I have is quite different from the example code I shared but the structure where I'm stuck is the same.

Just need a direction on the approach that's more suitable for handling this.

Here's What I did:

Looped through the data array and filtered Location objects
Tried to run another loop to filter out users object details

Problem I was having was have each user on individual HTML TD tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Location Name</th>
                <th colspan="2">Address</th>
                <th colspan="2">User Working</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    json_data = 
        {
            "data": [{

                "location": "Location 1",
                "Address": "location 1, Address",
                "users": [{
                    "name": "Location 1 User",
                    "state": "Active"
                }]

            }, {
                "location": "Location 2",
                "Address": "Location 2, Address",


                "users": [{
                        "name": "Location 2 User",
                        "state": "Active"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Location 2 User",
                        "state": "Inactive"
                    }
                ]

            }]
        } 
    //Accessing the JSON Document using these loops
    Object.keys(json_data['data']).forEach(key => {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tr.className = 'cell'
        document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].appendChild(tr);
        Object.keys(json_data['data'][key]).forEach(key2 => {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.setAttribute('colspan', '2');
            if (key2 === 'users') {
                Object.keys(json_data['data'][key][key2]).forEach(key3 => {
                    if (key3 > 0) {
                        td.innerHTML = td.innerHTML + ', ' + json_data['data'][key][key2][key3]['name'];
                    }
                    else {
                        td.innerHTML = td.innerHTML + json_data['data'][key][key2][key3]['name'];
                    }

                })
            }
            else {
                td.innerHTML = json_data['data'][key][key2];
            }
            document.getElementsByClassName('cell')[key].appendChild(td);
        })
    });


</script>
```

the code is pretty straightforward. The main thing to take note of is the Object.keys().forEach() loops and the createElements

There could be a much easier way to do this, but hey, it works.

Comment: Thank you Mannaroth! I appreciate your help with clearing my mind on what / how  to approach to map correctly.

I'm making this as correct answer because something that works, can be optimized :)

Thanks again for all the efforts!